# What are all products of an ozonolysis of alkenes using zinc and water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, ozone

I'm studying ozonolysis reactions in alkenes, and saw that in one of them there is the formation of $\ce{H2O2}$ (Can anyone explain from where?) that I presumed that reacts with $\ce{Zn}$, one of the reagents, as the following:
\begin{align}
\ce{2H2O2 &-> 2H2O + O2}  \\
\ce{2H2O + Zn &-> Zn(OH)2 + H2} \\ 
\hline  
\ce{H2O2 + Zn &-> Zn(OH)2}
\end{align}

The general reaction is 
\begin{align}
\ce{Unsaturated~compound (-C=C-) + O3 &-> Ozonide\\\\
Ozonide + Zn &-> R^1-(C=O)-R^2 + R^3-(C=O)-R^4 + X}
\end{align}

But one of my books shows that this $\ce{X}$ is $\ce{Zn(OH)2}$ only and other $\ce{ZnO}$ only. What about this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax.We prefer not to use markup in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: Your second equation is not balanced: $$\ce{2H2O + Zn -> Zn(OH)2 + H2}$$ Hence $$\ce{H2O2 + Zn -> Zn(OH)2}.$$

Comment: @Martin Ooops! Thank you! But $\ce{H2} $ and  $\ce{O2}$ will not form water?

Comment: Well I personally would assume that hydrogen peroxide directly reacts with zinc. So my estimate would be that there is no hydrogen or oxygen formation. It probably depends a lot on the mechanism and your $\ce{X}$ will ultimately depend on how much water and what pH is present.